# ¿Cómo reproducir archivos m3u8 en una página web?

Tags: jquery, html5, mediaplayer

Tengo enlazado archivos de m3u8 en mi sitio web, la cual solo se visualizan en Mozilla Firefox desde Android, solo desde ese navegador en dispositivo movil.

Pero en la `web` desde la `pc` o desde navegación normal en un ordenador no se visualizan, como puedo hacer que se visualicen, existe alguna forma con jQuery u algún nuevo atributo `HTML5` para hacer reproducir estos tipos de archivos multimedia o quizás algún plugin alguno en especial que no añada publicidad en mis archivos`m3u8`.

Comment: Buscando sobre m3u8, al final es un archivo con un texto dentro. quizas es una salvajada lo que voy a decir pero, si lo abres, lo lees y reproduces los archivos que contiene? en el fichero m3u8 aparecen las rutas de los ficheros a reproducir...

Comment: Deberías publicar lo que tienes de código así como el contenido del fichero .m3u8 y así podremos ayudarte.

Answer (score 3):

Me pareció interesante dar respuesta a esta antigua consulta y pese a que @Karla no nos dió mucha información, ni lo que había hecho para solucionar el problema.

Los archivos **M3U8** son listas de reproducción, igual que los archivos **M3U**. Los **M3U8** utilizan el estándar de codificación de caracteres UTF-8. Este estándar facilita que las listas de reproducción M3U8 contengan canciones con nombres escritos en distintos idiomas y con distintos conjuntos de caracteres.

Para poder trabajar con estos archivos en `HTML`,  hay una librería llamada `HLS.js` que es una biblioteca de JavaScript que implementa un cliente `HTTP Live Streaming` . Se basa en el video `HTML5` y en las extensiones de MediaSource para la reproducción.

Se implementa de esta forma:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src=hls.js"></script>
    <video id="video" controls></video>
    <script>
    if(Hls.isSupported())
    {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource('archivo.m3u8');
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function()
        {
            video.play();
        });
    }
    else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'))
    {
        video.src = 'archivo.m3u8';
        video.addEventListener('canplay',function()
        {
            video.play();
        });
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Más información aquí: https://hls-js.netlify.com/demo/

Comment: Para quién dio el voto negativo y no argumentó su razón, argumenté el motivo  del porque respondí esta consulta: Pese a que no cumple con el estándar de una buena pregunta, es bastante interesante y creo que es útil dar una respuesta que le pueda servir a otras personas. De hecho me sirvio a mi ya que me obligó a investigar y aprendí algo nuevo.